# Erro ao salvar arquivo - Já está sendo usado por outro processo

Tags: c#, arquivo

Quero ler o texto do TextBox (WinForms) e salvar no arquivo.

Está dando erro, dizendo que o arquivo está sendo usado em outro local.

```
StreamWriter escreverentrada = new StreamWriter(@"escreveentrada.txt",true);
        string valor = valortxt.ToString();
        string nome = nometxt.ToString();
        escreverentrada.WriteLine(valor);
        escreverentrada.Close();
```

Comment: O próprio erro diz o problema... ele está aberto em algum método. da uma olhada

Comment: Na verdade, eu criei o arquivo nesse método aí, e não teria a opção de usar em outro local. Porque é num metodo privado.

Comment: Se você criou ele pela aplicação deve ter esquecido de dar `Dispose()`.

Comment: E a leitura ali do TextLabel ta certo?

Comment: OU melhor, do TEXTBOX

Answer (score 2):

Tente utilizar o seu StreamWriter dentro de um bloco **using** para que seja feito o Dispose após o uso do recurso.

```
using (StreamWriter escreverentrada = new StreamWriter(@"escreveentrada.txt", true))
{
    string valor = valortxt.ToString();
    string nome = nometxt.ToString();
    escreverentrada.WriteLine(valor);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado mano, eu sou novato nessa vida de programação. Obrigado, acho que deu certo!

Comment: Por nada! Caso queira entender um pouco melhor sobre o uso da instrução "using", recomendo a leitura do material oficial da Microsoft. Segue o link: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement